# Does Order of the Dragon's Aid grant expanded uses of Aid Another?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, helping, cavalier

Does the [Order of the Dragon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/cavalier/orders/paizo-cavalier-orders/order-of-the-dragon/) ability [Aid Allies](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/cavalier/orders/paizo-cavalier-orders/order-of-the-dragon/#Aid_Allies_Ex) allow you to grant a different bonus than would normally be allowed by the Aid Another rules?

> At 2nd level, whenever an order of the dragon cavalier uses the aid another action to assist one of his allies, the ally receives a +3 bonus to his armor class, attack roll, saving throw, or skill check. At 8th level, and every six levels thereafter, this bonus increases by an additional +1.

The way Dragon-Order's ability is worded seems to allow that if a Cavalier was aiding an ally to climb a ladder, instead of the usually +2 granted to the Climb skill they could choose instead to increase their AC or Reflex by +3 (maybe they're expecting traps).

The ability also doesn't specify that the AC or Attack increase is against a specific target (like normal Aid Another) it's just a generic flat bonus with no other specifications.

Is this a correct reading? This does allow a lot of increased flexibility with the Aid rule, regardless of how a DM rules the numerical bonus stacks.

There is a lot of debate concerning the Aid Another stacking bonuses with the cavalier's [Order of the Dragon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/cavalier/orders/paizo-cavalier-orders/order-of-the-dragon/) [Aid Allies](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/cavalier/orders/paizo-cavalier-orders/order-of-the-dragon/#Aid_Allies_Ex) ability. You can read more [Here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/166006/what-are-the-balance-implications-of-letting-the-order-of-the-dragon-cavaliers), [Here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104034/aid-another-swift-aid-and-aid-allies-order-of-the-dragon/104041#104041), and [Here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104034/aid-another-swift-aid-and-aid-allies-order-of-the-dragon). For this question it does not care about the specific numerical value granted. Please disregard the specific values used in this question, it's more focused on how flexible this makes Aid Another.

Comment: RE: "The ability also doesn't specify that the AC or Attack increase is against a specific target (like normal Aid Another) it's just a generic flat bonus with no other specifications." It also doesn't specify a duration. Just sayin'.

Comment: More strikes to a not clearly written ability. I meant that more in relation to the first part of the question. Normally Aid Other grants AC/toHit vs a specific target you or your allies are threatening. But if you are able to grant a +AC to your ally when they are climbing then it's presumably a generic AC bonus vs everything.